# Build multiple executables from same code base

Tags: fortran, ninja, meson-build

I'm trying `Meson/Ninja` for what I otherwise do in `make`. I have source-files listed in the `src` variable, one of which is a program `prog.f90` with the statement `call ROUTINE`, and the preprocessor inserts names like `sub1, sub2...` for different test-executables `1.x, 2.x...`. Like this:

```
project('proj','fortran', version : '0')
flags = ['-cpp','-fmax-errors=3','-Wall','-fcheck=all','-fbacktrace','-Og', ...]
src = ['src/f1.f90', 'src/f2.f90', prog.f90, tools.f90, ...]

progs = [
    ['1.x',   '-DROUTINE=sub1'    ],
    ['2.x',   '-DROUTINE=sub2'    ],
    ['3.x',   '-DROUTINE=sub3'    ],
    ...
]

foreach p : progs
    executable(p[0],   src,fortran_args : flags + [p[1]])
endforeach
```

It is faster than using `make` but `Meson/Ninja` manages to use all cores for ca 1 second when changing a specific file, while make takes 2 seconds, but mostly runs on 1 core.

It seems like each executable gets its own build directory like `build/1x@exe` etc with all `.mod` and `.o` files matching `src`. And running `ninja -v` it seems like the file that changed is compiled as many times as there are executables. Meanwhile make only compiles it ones (but then compiles other files due to dependencies stated between objects instead of modules).

So what is the smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to first make a `static_library()` from all other sources files (i.e. everything that is *not* `prog.f90`), and to add it in the `link_with` kwarg of your executable.

This would end up something like this:

```
# Note that 'prog.f90' is no longer in here
src = files('src/f1.f90', 'src/f2.f90', 'tools.f90', ...)

# This is the static library which will only get compiled once
lib = static_library(src, fortran_args: flags)


progs = [
    ['1.x',   '-DROUTINE=sub1'    ],
    ['2.x',   '-DROUTINE=sub2'    ],
    ['3.x',   '-DROUTINE=sub3'    ],
    ...
]

foreach p : progs
    executable(p[0], 'prog.f90', fortran_args: flags + [p[1]], link_with: lib)
endforeach
```